# Sort an arraylist of objects in java

Tags: java, sorting

I'm working on creating a simulating of some different CPU scheduling algorithms and also wanted to learn a new language at the same time.  The trouble I'm running into is trying to sort an arraylist of processes based on their arrival time.  The error I'm running into is that there is no suitable method found for Collections.sort(processes), and I'm not really sure what to do.

Process.java

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Process implements Comparable
{

    private Random generator;
    private String name;
    private int burstTime;
    private int priority;
    private int arrivalTime;

    /**
     * Process constructor where the user choose the values
     * @param nameValue name of the process
     * @param burstTimeValue burst time of the process
     * @param priorityValue priority of the process
     * @param arrivalTimeValue arrival time of the process
     */
    public Process(String nameValue, int burstTimeValue, int priorityValue,
            int arrivalTimeValue)
    {
        name = nameValue;
        burstTime = burstTimeValue;
        priority = priorityValue;
        arrivalTime = arrivalTimeValue;
    }

    /**
     * Process constructor that randomizes the values of
     * name, burst time, priority, and arrival time.
     */
    public Process()
    {
        generator = new Random();
        name = "Process" + generator.nextInt(10000);
        burstTime = generator.nextInt(10);
        priority = generator.nextInt(5);
        arrivalTime = generator.nextInt(30);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the name of the process
     * @return name the name of the process
     */
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the name of the process
     * @param aValue value to set the process name to
     */
    public void setName(String aValue)
    {
        name = aValue;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the burst time of the process
     * @return burstTime the burst time of the process
     */
    public int getBurstTime()
    {
        return burstTime;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the burst time of a process
     * @param aValue the value for the burst time of a process
     */
    public void setBurstTime(int aValue)
    {
        burstTime = aValue;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the priority value of the process
     * @return priority the priority of the process
     */
    public int getPriority()
    {
        return priority;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the priority of a process
     * @param aValue value for priority
     */
    public void setPriority(int aValue)
    {
        priority = aValue;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the arrival time of the process
     * @return arrival time the arrival time of the process
     */
    public int getArrivalTime()
    {
        return arrivalTime;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the arrival time value
     * @param aValue value for arrival time
     */
    public void setArrivalTime(int aValue)
    {
        arrivalTime = aValue;
    }

    /**
     * Overrides the toString method from the String class
     * Returns a printout of the object's variables
     * @return printout of the object's variables
     */
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Process[name=" + name + " bTime=" + burstTime
                + " priority=" + priority + " aTime=" + arrivalTime +"]";
    }

    /**
     * Compares two process objects
     * @param otherObject another process object
     * @return the order of two processes
     */
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object otherObject)
    {
        Process other = (Process) otherObject;
        if (arrivalTime < other.arrivalTime) return -1;
        if (arrivalTime == other.arrivalTime) return 0;
        return 1;
    } 
}
```

Comparable.java

```
public interface Comparable
{
    int compareTo(Object otherObject);
}
```

Cpu.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
public class Cpu implements
{
    private ArrayList<Process> processes;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public Cpu()
    {
        processes = new ArrayList<Process>();
    }

    /**
     * Adds a process to the ArrayList
     * @param p the process that is being added
     */
    public void addProcess(Process p)
    {
        processes.add(p);
    }

    public void sort()
    {
        Collections.sort(processes);
    }      
}
```

Comment: You're implementing "Comparable", and you've got a "compareTo()" method - good.  But don't you want "processes.sort()" instead of "Collections.sort(processes)"?

Comment: Whoops - I didn't notice you were writing your *own* "interface Comparable".  As Sibbo pointed out - that won't work ;)

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement [`java.lang.Comparable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). Writing your own won't work, because it's in another package.

So just add the import declaration in for your Process class and delete your self made Comparable interface. (+ see first comment)

Comment: +1 for this guy. Also, I'd recommend implementing `Comparable<Process>` rather than just `Comparable`. That way you don't have to cast your object.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom Comperator which will compare two Process objects based on the arrival time.
Collections class has an overloaded sort() method that takes a collection (list, array) and a Comperator.

Here is an excellent example for doing so:

http://www.javadeveloper.co.in/java-example/java-comparator-example.html

Please see Sibbo's response as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've made ​​a function to sort a list of objects by a specific variable in the model class. It may not directly match the one you need, but maybe you can take the idea. I'm using reflection to be able to sort any class models with any data type.

```
 public Vector sort(Vector list, String kelas, String s, String asc) throws NoSuchMethodException {

        try {
            // Creates an object of type Class which contains the information of
            // the class String
            Object[] obj = list.toArray();
            Object[] args = {};
            Class cl = Class.forName(kelas);
            Method toSort = cl.getMethod(s, null);
            if (asc.equalsIgnoreCase("desc")) {
                if (toSort.getReturnType().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("int") || toSort.getReturnType().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("double")) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                        for (int j = i; j < obj.length; j++) {
                            try {
                                if (Double.parseDouble(toSort.invoke(obj[i], args).toString()) < Double.parseDouble(toSort.invoke(obj[j], args).toString())) {
                                    Object temp = obj[i];
                                    obj[i] = obj[j];
                                    obj[j] = temp;
                                }
                            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(DbBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(DbBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(DbBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                        for (int j = i; j < obj.length; j++) {
                            try {
                                if (toSort.invoke(obj[i], args).toString().compareToIgnoreCase(toSort.invoke(obj[j], args).toString()) < 0) {
                                    Object temp = obj[i];
                                    obj[i] = obj[j];
                                    obj[j] = temp;
                                }
                            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(DbBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(DbBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(DbBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (toSort.getReturnType().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("int") || toSort.getReturnType().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("double")) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                        for (int j = i; j < obj.length; j++) {
                            try {
                                if (Double.parseDouble(toSort.invoke(obj[i], args).toString()) > Double.parseDouble(toSort.invoke(obj[j], args).toString())) {
                                    Object temp = obj[i];
                                    obj[i] = obj[j];
                                    obj[j] = temp;
                                }
                            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(DbBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(DbBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(DbBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                        for (int j = i; j < obj.length; j++) {
                            try {
                                if (toSort.invoke(obj[i], args).toString().compareToIgnoreCase(toSort.invoke(obj[j], args).toString()) > 0) {
                                    Object temp = obj[i];
                                    obj[i] = obj[j];
                                    obj[j] = temp;
                                }
                            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(DbBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(DbBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(DbBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            list = new Vector();
            for (int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                list.add(obj[i]);
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }
```

you can call that function as simple as this :

```
Vector sortedList=sort(UnsortedList, "bean.Items", "getItemName", "asc");
```

This line will sort my item list (item is a model class) based on Item Name ascending